# Delphi Warning W1073 Combining signed type and unsigned 64-bit type - treated as an unsigned type

Tags: delphi, types, warnings

I get the subject warning on the following line of code;

```
SelectedFilesSize := SelectedFilesSize +
  UInt64(IdList.GetPropertyValue(TShellColumns.Size)) *
  ifthen(Selected, 1, -1);
```

Specifically, the IDE highlights the third line.

SelectedFilesSize is declared as UInt64.

The code appears to work when I run it;  if I select an item, its file size is added to the total, if I deselect a file its size is subtracted.

I know I can suppress this warning with  {$WARN COMBINING_SIGNED_UNSIGNED64 OFF}.

Can someone explain?  Will there be an unforeseen impact if SelectedFilesSize gets huge?  Or an impact on a specific target platform?

Delphi 10.3, Win32 and Win64 targets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work here, but the warning is right.

If you multiply a *UInt64* with `-1`, you are actually multiplying it with `$FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`. The final result will be a 128 bit value, **but the lower 64 bits will be the same as for a signed multiplication** (that is also why the code generator often produces an `imul` opcode, even for unsiged multiplication: the lower bits will be correct, just the — *unused* — higher bits won't be). The upper 64 bits won't be used anyway, so they don't matter.

If you add that (actually negative) value to another *UInt64* (e.g. *SelectedFilesSize*), the 64 bit *result* will be correct again. The CPU does not discriminate between positive or negative values when adding. The resulting CPU *flags* (carry, overflow) will indicate overflow, but if you ignore that by not using range or overflow checks, your code will be fine.

Your code will likely produce a runtime error if range or overflow checks are on, though.

In other words, **this works because any excess upper bit — the 64th bit and above — can be ignored**. Otherwise, the values would be wrong. See example.

**Example**

Say your `IdList.GetPropertyValue(TShellColumns.Size)` is 420. Then you are performing:

```
$00000000000001A4 * $FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF = $00000000000001A3FFFFFFFFFFFFFF5C
```

This is a huge **but positive** number, but fortunately the lower 64 bits (`$FFFFFFFFFFFFFF5C`) can be interpreted as `-420` (a really negative value in 128 bit would be `$FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF5C` or `-420`).

Now say your `SelectedFileSize` is `100000` (or hex `$00000000000186A0`). Then you get:

```
$00000000000186A0 + $FFFFFFFFFFFFFF5C = $00000000000184FC 
(or actually $100000000000184FC, but the top bit -- the carry -- is ignored).
```

`$00000000000184FC` is `99580` in decimal, so exactly the value you wanted.

Comment: I know we're talking extremes here, but I also remember when 1.44 MB floppies seemed huge ...

So, if SelectedFilesSize is $FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, UInt64(IdList.GetPropertyValue(TShellColumns.Size)) returns $FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, and ifthen(Selected, 1, -1) returns -1 then the calculation will still work and return 0?

It works because internally the computer is doing 128-bit arithmetic and doing $FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF - $FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF as 128-bit arithmetic? A calculation would only break if it produced an interim result that was greater than 127 bits?

Comment: $FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF * $FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF = $FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0000000000000001 (128 bit). The top 64 bits will be discarded, so you get $0000000000000001, or simply 1 (which is the same result as if you had used Int64(-1) * Int64(-1)). Multiply that with whatever you like. The currrent computers will only do 64 bit addition. There is a 65th bit, the carry, but no high level language regard that. Also adding $FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (aka UINt64(-1) ) to itself will result in $FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE, which is Uint64(-2). So for 64 bit, the result wil be right. That is slightly different in assembler.

Comment: FWIW, in Intel 64 bit, 128 bit (2 registers, RDX and RAX) are only used for unsigned division (the dividend is 128 bit) and unsigned multiplication (the result is 128 bit). Additions and subtractions only return an extra carry (or borrow) bit. These things can be used directly in assembler, but not in high level languages. There, the variables generally remain restricted to 64 bit, so 64bit x 64 bit returns 64 bit again. Of course 128 bit and higher can be simulated, but that requires quite some extra work.